# Can a pure DDD approach be used with NHibernate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, repository, domain-driven-design

I've been reading up on DDD a little bit, and I am confused how this would fit in when using an ORM like NHibernate.

Right now I have a .NET MVC application with fairly "fat" controllers, and I'm trying to figure out how best to fix that. Moving this business logic into the model layer would be the best way to do this, but I am unsure how one would do that.

My application is set up so that NHibernate's session is managed by an HttpModule (gets session / transaction out of my way), which is used by repositories that return the entity objects (Think S#arp arch... turns out a really duplicated a lot of their functionality in this). These repositories are used by DataServices, which right now are just wrappers around the Repositories (one-to-one mapping between them, e.g. UserDataService takes a UserRepository, or actually a Repository). These DataServices right now only ensure that data annotations decorating the entity classes are checked when saving / updating.

In this way, my entities are really just data objects, but do not contain any real logic. While I could put some things in the entity classes (e.g. an "Approve" method), when that action needs to do something like sending an e-mail, or touching other non-related objects, or, for instance, checking to see if there are any users that have the same e-mail before approving, etc., then the entity would need access to other repositories, etc. Injecting these with an IoC wouldn't work with NHibernate, so you'd have to use a factory pattern I'm assuming to get these. I don't see how you would mock those in tests though.

So the next most logical way to do it, I would think, would be to essentially have a service per controller, and extract all of the work being done in the controller currently into methods in each service. I would think that this is breaking with the DDD idea though, as the logic is now no longer contained in the actual model objects.

The other way of looking at that I guess is that each of those services forms a single model with the data object that it works against (Separation of data storage fields and the logic that operates on it), but I just wanted to see what others are doing to solve the "fat controller" issue with DDD while using an ORM like NHibernate that works by returning populated data objects, and the repository model.

**Updated**
I guess my problem is how I'm looking at this: NHibernate seems to put business objects (entities) at the bottom of the stack, which repositories then act on. The repositories are used by services which may use multiple repositories and other services (email, file access) to do things. I.e: App > Services > Repositories > Business Objects

The pure DDD approach I'm reading about seems to reflect an Active Record bias, where the CRUD functions exist in the business objects (This I call User.Delete directly instead of Repository.Delete from a service), and the actual business object handles the logic of things that need to be done in this instance (Like emailing the user, and deleting files belonging to the user, etc.). I.e. App > (Services) > Business Objects > Repositories

With NHibernate, it seems I would be better off using the first approach given the way NHibernate functions, and I am looking for confirmation on my logic. Or if I'm just confused, some clarification on how this layered approach is supposed to work. My understanding is that if I have an "Approve" method that updates the User model, persists it, and lets say, emails a few people, that this method should go on the User entity object, but to allow for proper IoC so I can inject the messagingService, I need to do this in my service layer instead of on the User object.

From a "multiple UI" point of view this makes sense, as the logic to do things is taken out of my UI layer (MVC), and put into these services... but I'm essentially just factoring the logic out to another class instead of doing it directly in the controller, and if I am not ever going to have any other UI's involved, then I've just traded a "fat controller" for a "fat service", since the service is essentially going to encapsulate a method per controller action to do it's work.

Comment: I'm not sure what "pure DDD approach" reflects an active record bias. That's decidedly unlike anything I remember in Eric Evans' book. What source are you using that suggests entities use ActiveRecord?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can use Castle ActiveRecord if you want Nhibernate to use ActiveRecord instead of a DDD approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DDD does **not** have an Active Record slant.  *Delete* is **not** a method that should be on an Entity (like User) in DDD.

NHibernate does support a DDD approach very well, because of how completely divorced it remains from your entity classes.

> when that action needs to do something
>   like sending an e-mail, or touching
>   other non-related objects

One piece of the puzzle it seems you are missing is Domain Events.  A domain entity shouldn't send an email directly.  It should raise an event in the Domain that some significant event has happened.  Implement a class whose purpose is to send the email when the event occurs, and register it to listen for the Domain Event.

> or, for instance, checking to see if
>   there are any users that have the same
>   e-mail before approving

This should probably be checked *before* submitting the call to "approve," rather than in the function that does the approving.  Push the decision up a level in calling code.

> So the next most logical way to do it,
>   I would think, would be to essentially
>   have a service per controller

This can work, if it's done with the understanding that the service is an entry point for the client.  The service's purpose here is to take in parameters in a DTO from the front end/client and translate that into method calls against an entity in order to perform the desired funcitonality.

Comment: I am not thinking in terms of events like that, no... So what you are saying is that entities should ONLY have methods that deal with modifying the domain state (e.g. changing values). Anything outside of this should be raised as an event, and event handlers used to do the other things, like deleting files, and sending e-mails?

Comment: Yeah, basically, domain state *is* what the entities are in charge of. Events feel very natural for implementing many requirements, and they have value in and of themselves (capturing intent behind changes, audit, etc.).  Though I wouldn't say ONLY or Any.  Sometimes it's more straight-forward to have an exception to the rule. It's always a judgement call and a decision, but events have helped me see where to put functionality with more clarity in a lot of cases.

Comment: Is there a good forum out there to discuss these things? I feel I am going to have a lot more questions...

Comment: So the Controller talks to the Application Service and says "ApproveUser", the application service gets the user (Via NHibernate through the Repository<User>), manipulates the User by calling User.Approve, and saves, and then handles return to the Controller. Who in this line raises the event? I would assume the Approve method on the User... But then in the case of a Delete, which is handled by the repository, does the REPOSITORY then raise the delete event?

Comment: You're right on track.  Yes, Approve raises the event: UserApproved.  And yes, the Repository has the responsibility of Removing the User (Repo's have collection semantics) and therefore also has the responsibility of raising the event that a User has been Removed.  Repositories are as much a part of the domain as the entities, so both are valid places for notable events to occur.

Comment: The DDD/CQRS google group has good info.  http://groups.google.com/group/dddcqrs  There's a couple other groups like that, probably one specifically DDD and another specifically CQRS.  I recommend looking at CQRS because the practices and patterns that make up CQRS are powerful, simple, and fit well with DDD.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to you question is yes, in fact, I find NHibernate enhances DDD - you can focus on developing (and altering) your domain model with a code first approach, then easily retro-fit persistence later using NHibernate.

As you build out your domain model following DDD, I would expect that much of the business logic that's found you way into you MVC controllers should probably reside in your domain objects. In my first attempt at using ASP.NET MVC I quickly found myself in the same position as yourself - fat controllers and an anemic domain model.

To avoid this, I'm now following the approach of keeping a rich domain model that implements the business logic and using MVC's model as essentially simple data objects used by my views. This simplifies my controllers - they interact with my domain model and provide simple data objects (from the MVC model) to the views.

**Updated**

> The pure DDD approach I'm reading about seems to reflect an Active Record bias...

To me the active record pattern means entities are aware of their persistance mechanism and an entity maps directly to a database table record. This is one way of using NHibernate e.g. see [Castle Active Record](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/), however, I find this pollutes domain enitities with knowledge of their persistence mechanism. Instead, typically, I'll have a repository per [aggregate root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) in my domain model which implements an abstract repository. The abstract repository provides basic CRUD methods such as:

```
public IList<TEntity> GetAll()
public TEntity GetById(int id)
public void SaveOrUpdate(TEntity entity)
public void Delete(TEntity entity)
```

.. which my concrete repositories can supplement/extend.

See [this post on The NHibernate FAQ](http://web.archive.org/web/20110503184234/http://blogs.hibernatingrhinos.com/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/08/the-repository-pattern.aspx) which I've based a lot of my stuff on. Also remember, NHibernate (depending on how you set up your mappings) will allow you to de-persist a complete object graph, i.e. your aggregate root plus all the objects hanging off it and once you've finished working with it, can cascade saves through you entire object graph, this certainly isn't active record.

> ...since the service is essentially going to encapsulate a method per controller action to do it's work...

I still think you should consider what functionality that you currently have in your controllers should, more logically, be implemented within your domain objects. e.g. in your approval example, I think it would be sensible for an entity to expose an approve method which does whatever it needs to do to within the entity and if, as in your example, needs to send emails, delegate this to a service. Services should be reserved for [cross-cutting concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern). Then, once you've finished working with your domain objects, pass them back to your repository to persist changes.

A couple of books I've found useful on these topics are:
[Domain-Driven Design by Eric Evans](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215)
[Applying Domain-Driven Design and Patterns by Jimmy Nilsson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321268202)

Comment: Yes, I use the ViewModel approach for my Controller to View data as well. My question revolves around the fact that DDD seems to indicate more of an active record like design (e.g., a User has a 'Delete' method that goes through and deletes all the files associated with a user). Using the repository pattern muddies this more. See my notes above.

Comment: @Graham, yes that article is the basis for my system too. My issue is trying to understand where things get sliced up. I'm starting to get some of this now, and am seeing ways to do things, for instance injecting my requirements at method run time (Instead of Form.Approve() I'd have Form.Approve(currentUser, booleanSomething, etc)). Then things that need to happen out-of-context of the domain (Which is the database entities) can be handled by raised events.

Comment: "will allow you to de-persist a complete object graph" This is why NHibernate is so powerful.  The flexibility to define object models almost any way needed, and map it to a relational schema, and then it picks up all the data changes auto-magically.  Saves *tons* of code.

Comment: @Michael: Good pickup on injecting requirements as method parameters.  That's another pattern that simplifies DDD and where the pieces fit quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The only limitations NHibernate creates for classes is all methods/properties must be virtual and a class must have a default constructor (can be internal or protected). Otherwise, it does not [edit] interfere with object structure and can map to pretty complex models.

Comment: Did you mean "Otherwise, it does **not** interfere with object structure" ?

Comment: Well, my question about the deletion method was that it seemed that if OTHER ACTIONS needed to take place on the deletion of an object, that the delete method should go in the entity. The Domain Events methodology makes that MUCH cleaner for me for things like emailing, now that I understand it. The other option, of course, is to do these extra actions in the application service layers, which may be better for, say, deleting related files when an entity is deleted from the persistence store. I was just having difficulty understanding how non-persistence related events fit in.